# Taxonomy View and Paths

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

I have a view set up to display all my taxonomy nodes for "Classified Categories" Vocabulary, in the view I have set up the path to be /Dogs however when it lists the terms they are all linked to /Dogs/(term) and this will then display nothing, but if I change the path from /Dogs/ to /Classified-Categories/(term) it will show.

I've had a look at setting up patterns for my URLs but seem to have no joy. Further on this the terms with spaces are linked with %20 in and will not show even in the changed format; only when I replace the %20 with - will they show.

I'm pretty stuck on getting this to work especially being a Drupal newbie.

This is a screenshot from my current configuration of my view.

[image: Screen 1] [image: Screen 2] [image: Screen 3] [image: Screen 4]

Both "Link this field to its taxonomy term page" and "Convert spaces in term names to hyphens" are ticked.**

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please keep in mind that images here are shrunk to about 600px width, so if possible, resize your browser's window to something around or under that width to avoid scaling. It will make it easier for us to read.

Comment: @Molot Split it down to a few more pictures, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the filter and only add the contextual filter with taxonomy term id.
also change path to /Dog/%.

Comment: This is working, however due to having % in the path I can no longer use it as a menu link. I want to be able to display a list of all the terms. I have set up in the contextual filter when the value is not in the url display a summary but I can't seem to navigate to the base page.

Comment: use Provide default value instead of display a summary also select "type= term id from url"